# Переопределение обьектов

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Имеется заголовочный файл с таким содержимым:

```
const int ATTRIBUTES = 9;

struct Food
{
wstring category;
wstring name;
double calory;
double proteins; // double - кол-во белков, string - вид белка
wstring proteinsType;
double carbohydr;
unsigned int glycemic_index;
double fats;
wstring fatsType;

Food() : category(L"default"), name(L"default"), calory(0.0), proteins(0.0), proteinsType(L"default"),
    carbohydr(0.0), glycemic_index(0), fats(0.0), fatsType(L"default")
{}

Food(wstring categ, wstring nm, double cal, double prot, wstring type_prot, double carboh,
    int glic_ind, double fat, wstring type_fat)
    : category(categ), name(nm), calory(cal), proteins(prot), proteinsType(type_prot),
    carbohydr(carboh), glycemic_index(glic_ind), fats(fat), fatsType(type_fat)
{}
};

Food calcWeight(const Food& f, const int& weight)
{
Food temp;
int new_w = weight / 100;
temp.calory *= new_w;
temp.proteins *= new_w;
temp.carbohydr *= new_w;
temp.fats *= new_w;
return temp;
}
```

Куда бы я не ткнул эти определения, ни в отдельный заголовочный файл, не в сам исходный код, компилятор пишет, что все обьекты здесь уже переопределены, хотя я точно знаю, что определены они один раз. Даже объявив новую переменную в этом файле, компилятор все равно пишет, что она уже переопределена. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Думаю, проблема в `calcWeight`, так как нарушается One Defnition Rule.

Делайте правильно, как советует @Free_ze: в header помещайте только декларации, а реальный код — в .cpp.

Comment: Удалил реализацию из заголовочного файла, добавил в cpp файл, все равно не помогло. Ошибки всё те же.
Еще один важный факт! Если подключить хедер и срршник к другому проекту, все работает.

Comment: @dbs1024 include guard стоит? Хедер не может тем или иным образом многократно подтягиваться?

Comment: 1 хедер:

    #define FOOD_H
    #ifdef FOOD_H
    #include <string>
    ...
    #endif

2 хедер:

    #define IO_FILE_H
    #ifdef IO_FILE_H
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include "food.h"
    ...
    #endif

ВСЕ! Убрал хедер food во втором хедере, проблема ушла, так как в main.cpp я тоже подключал food.h

Answer (score 1):

[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024), что делает эта конструкция?

```
#define FOOD_H
#ifdef FOOD_H
```

(правильно, ничего (полезного))

Answer (score 0):

В заголовочных файлах должны быть только объявления, inline-функции и шаблоны, без определений.
Кроме того, хотелось бы видеть пример файла, куда это инклудится, иначе не ясно, что с чем конфликтует.
Ну и, конечно, ребилдол от вашего недуга не помогает?